# WebView cannot load html data more than 2 times

Tags: android, webview

I am using two WebViews in one of my activity to showing html pages stored in db, they are made to show one after another controlled by finger flings on screen. But the problem is that once the webview loaded html data, it cannot be changed anymore. The codes below can show my case:

```
 WebView.loadData("a","text/html","UTF-8");

 WebView.loadData("b","text/html","UTF-8");
```

the WebView won't change the content to "b", it is still showing "a".

here is the layout file I am using for this activity

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewLeft" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewRight" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone has any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try putting a `WebView.stopLoading()` in between the two pages you are loading. The Webview may be trying to load the previous data, and might not stop until the previous page has loaded.

I have used the WebView API before, just not in this context. I hope this is your solution.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But it still now working if I put these webviews in a viewFilpper. Once it get a html data rendered, it can not be changed anymore.

Comment: Actually, the webview cannot be changed only after calling viewFlipper.showNext or showPrevious method to switch them.if I do no switch thing, it works just fine.